# How to add popdown div to show search results

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have search returning multiple resulting anchor tags to other pages. How do I show them on top of the other parts of the page absolutely?

```
<style>
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        height: 250px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #7d807e;
    }

    .box1 {
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .box1:hover {
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0.5;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        transform-style: all;
        transition-duration: 2s;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {

        <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger box1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" asp-area="" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Details" asp-route-productId="@product.Id"> <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="position-absolute top-100 start-50 translate-middle mt-1" fill="var(--bs-secondary)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.247 11.14L2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z" /></svg> @product.Name - @product.Price</a>
    }
</div>
```